How to impleement Bye-week in Round robin algorithm for even number of teams
I have used round robin algorithm to generate the schedule for teams, which works for the N teams to play N-1 games in N-1 rounds & play 1 time with all other teams before playing second time with any of them.
To implement Bye-weeks, for odd number of teams, it automatically gives one Bye-week to each team. Now, i have to implement Bye-weeks for Even number of teams(N), where each team can play with other teams in total N rounds(as for 1 round team will be on bye-week). Can anyone help me how should i allocate Bye-weeks to teams(i consider that for even number of teams, it will be better to give same week as bye-week to two teams).
Here i am sharing the code, how i implemented the round robin algorithm
    $roundMatchups = [];
    $matchups = [];
    $teamCount = count($teams);
    $opponentsCount = $teamCount  - 1;
    for($round = 1; $round <= $opponentsCount; $round++) {

        $singleRoundMatchups = [];
        //Generate matchups for this round
        for ($i = 0; $i < $teamCount / 2; $i++) {

            $home = $teams[$i];
            $away = $teams[$teamCount - $i - 1];

            $singleRoundMatchups[] = [
                 home' => $home,
                'away' => $away,
            ];
        }

        $roundMatchups[] = $singleRoundMatchups;

        // Rotate teams (except the first one) to get new matchups in next round
        $lastTeam = array_pop($teams);
        array_splice($teams, 1, 0, $lastTeam); // Insert last team after first
    }

    $matchups = collect($roundMatchups)->flatten(1)->toArray();
}

